# Get Records Fields with SuiteTalk Netsuite

Tags: php, netsuite, suitetalk

I'm working with the PHPToolkit to connect to SuiteTalk from Netsuite, and I need to get the standard and custom fields.

The unique way I found is get one previously created on netsuite, get the record and extract the fields. But must be other way to get the Object Structure

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you are trying to get the object definitions for NetSuite objects. If so, you will need to make use of the WSDL as a web reference, found here: [NetSuite WSDL](https://webservices.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2016_2_0/netsuite.wsdl?&tlspname=Developers%20:%20Developer%20Resources%20:%20SuiteTalk%20:%20SuiteTalk%20Documentation&tllabel=v20162SwsdLink&tlspurl=/portal/developers/resources/suitetalk-documentation.shtml&tlspregion=region3&tlcrossdomain=true)

I am not sure how this is done with PHP and which IDE you are working in. I am sure you can search online for how to add web references to your project in whichever dev environment you are working.

Comment: I don't think suggesting someone to go google the solution is a useful answer at all. Furthermore, the question doesn't suggest lack of knowledge of SOAP nor of the function of a WSDL file.